# Übersetzung von »Vom Zehnten das Gebot, bezeugt dadurch einst Gott.«

Tags: translation, meaning, poetry

Ich versuche ein Gedicht von meinem Ururgroßvater ins Englische zu übersetzen. Diesen Vers kann ich nicht übersetzen:

> Glücks Klee die Kinder bringen,
>   Vernehmt Ihr's, was sie singen,
>   Vom Zehnten das Gebot,
>   Bezeugt dadurch einst Gott.

Den ersten Teil kann ich übersetzen:

> The children bring the clover of luck,
>   Listen to what they sing,

Aber den zweiten kann ich nicht verstehen. Bedeutet es, dass Gott einst durch das Gebot vom Zehnten bezeugt hat? Aber was bedeutet das eigentlich? Vielleicht, auf Englisch: »God once testified through the commandment of tithes/tithing«?

Für den Fall, dass es hilft: Er war ein religiöser Mann und christlich und das Gedicht war für den Geburtstag von einer Familienfreundin geschrieben.

Comment: Könnet das ein (literarischer) Verweis auf das Zehnte Gebot sein?

Comment: Ich würde es auch eher als Verweis auf den Zehnten (die Steuer) sehen. Die vorgeschlagene Übersetzung wäre dann nicht so schlecht.

Comment: Ja, ich dachte, dass es von Zehnten ("Tithing or tithes") sprach, und hatte nicht von den Zehn Geboten gedacht.  Aber ich weiß noch nicht, was das bedeutet! :)

Comment: Kannst Du etwas mehr Kontext angeben oder besteht das ganze Gedicht aus zusammenhangslosen Zweizeilern?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Das ganze Gedicht besteht von Versen, die vier Zeilen haben. Die meisten machen Sinn, aber die sind nicht sehr verwandt mit diesem Vers, und würden kein mehr Kontext geben, glaube ich.

Comment: Ich würde mir auch mehr vom Gedicht wünschen, den Vers davor und den danach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Versuch einer Interpretation. Wenn man den Satz schreibt als

> [durch] das Gebot vom Zehnten wurde Gott einst bezeugt.

Dann heisst das in heutiger Sprache, dass man durch die Ablieferung des Zehnten seine Achtung Gott gegenüber zum Ausdruck gebracht hat (weil das Gebot, den Zehnten zu zahlen, von Gott kommt).

Comment: Danke! Ich lerne Deutsche seit nur einem Jahr, und kann nicht den ganzen letzen Satz verstehen... Sagt es, dass wenn man Zehnten bezahlt, bringt es Gottes Achtung zu ihm, der das Zehnten bezahlt?

Comment: Oh, dafür sprichst du aber schon ziemlich gut deutsch. I was trying to say that by tithing, you express your respect towards god, because it is gods law (according to the bible) that you have to pay tithes. This is similar to saying that good will respect you if you pay, but the sentence rather does not mean it that way.

Comment: OK, danke! Hast du irgendwelche Ideen, wie es ins Englische zu übersetzen? Es passt nicht wohl mit dem Vers... Würde "Through the law of tithing / one respects God" als Übersetzung funktionieren?

Comment: Ja, diese Variante kommt dem Sinn des Originals meines Erachtens ziemlich nahe (wobei ich jetzt nicht grad der Experte für literarisches Englisch bin).

Comment: Das Gebot den 10ten zu zahlen kommt ja von Gott, so man an diesen Gott überhaupt glaubt - das würde also behaupten Gott bezeugt sich selbst, was natürlich Unfug ist. Dass man sich an dieses Gebot vom Zehnten, den man zu zahlen hat, hält, damit bezeugt man Gott.

Comment: OK, danke für die Hilfe, alle!  Ich weiß nicht, ob ich es als "Through the Law of Tithing / God once witnessed" oder "Through the Law of Tithing / One may witness to God", aber danke für die Ideen!  Es sei denn, es gibt andere Antworten, werde ich dieses Antwort akzeptieren. Danke!

Answer (score 5):

“Vom Zehnten das Gebot” can be written as “das Gebot des Zehntens” and does actually mean the commandment of tithing.

The phrase has been extracted from the main sentence. More natural, the sentence would be:

> Gott hat durch das Gebot des Zehnten es einst (früher) bezeugt.

The children, happy that they found the clover of luck, sang that blessings had been testified to or attested to (promised) by God when he gave the commandment for tithing, and that the clover of luck was a shadow, a foretaste, a promisse of what is to come. The whole thing wrapped into the question wheather you heard about them singing.

When God in Malachi reinstituted the tithe, he said that we should test him whether he would not open the floodgates of heaven and pour out blessings. The clover of luck was a sign for such blessings.

This would be my tranlsation then:

> The children bring the clover of luck.
>   Can you hear what they sing:
>   ”The commandment of tithing
>   will God once attest to through this (sign of the clover of luck).”

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I think you got it!

Answer (score 1):

Auch ich bin der Meinung, dass hier vom Zehnten, also der zehnprozentigen Abgabe an die Kirche, die Rede ist. Allerdings kann "einst" nicht nur früher bedeuten, sondern auch: später einmal, in ferner Zukunft, künftig. Ein etwas veralteter Ausdruck dafür wäre: dereinst. Und das ist hier meiner Meinung nach auch der Fall, denn sonst müßte am Anfang der Zeile eigentlich "Bezeugte" stehen.